# Can't find Timeshift snapshots to delete

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage, snapshot

Timeshift failed creating a snapshot. But the 140gb of space it took have not been returned.

I've looked in the timeshift folder and the snapshots are empty. Inside the program it also says there are no snapshots.

Have rebooted and still nothing.

Comment: You'll need to provide details about how you know the space is still used, etc if you want people to be able to help. All anyone can do based on what you have written is say OK, then.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks @OrganicMarble

Answer (score 0):

I found the files in root/home/.local/share/trash.

Before I had looked in /home/.local/share/trash